# ComboBox's SelectedIndexChanged event not being called on Enter

Tags: vb.net

I'm working on VS 2010 with VB using .NET Framework 4.0

I have a `combobox`. It has some items in it and displays just fine. Here's where it gets a little weird:

If I click the drop-down arrow on the `combobox` and CLICK on the item I want, `SelectedIndexChanged` is called - good.

If I click inside the text area of the `combobox` and start typing what I want selected and finish it by pressing the up (or down) key, `SelectedIndexChanged` is called - also good.

If I click the drop-down arrow on the `combobox` and start typing what I want selected and finish it by pressing ENTER, `SelectedIndexChanged` is not called - PROBLEM.

Is there a different event that is caused by the `ENTER` in the last case? I've tried using the `TextChanged` and `TextUpdate` events, but those do not seem to be working:

```
Private Sub cmbStatus_TextChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmbStatus.TextChanged
If e.Equals(Keys.Enter) Then
    Call SomeMethod()
End If
```

Should I use something besides `e.Equals(Keys.Enter)`?

Is there another event I should be looking for?

**EDIT:**
An example of the items in the `ComboBox` are:

- 10 - NEW ENTRY AND COMPLETENESS CHECK            `---> this is the most common type`
- 13 - ASSIGNED TO TRB/HRB                         `---> there are a few with '/'`
- 60 - EXTERNAL (HOLD UNTIL FURTHER NOTICE)        `---> there are a few with '(' and ')'`

Basically, the type of each listing is "## - SOME TEXT".

Comment: The problem is that the SelectedIndexChanged does not get called when the value is typed and changes the Selected Index. WHY?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Option Strict On
Public Class Form1
    Friend WithEvents ComboBox1 As New ComboBox With {.Parent = Me}
    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        ComboBox1.Items.AddRange({"hello", "tes1ted", "word", "item", "tes2ted"})
        ComboBox1.Text = ComboBox1.Items(0).ToString
    End Sub
    Private Sub ComboBox1_KeyUp(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As KeyEventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.KeyUp
        'You can put this in the keydown event, or adapt it a small bit and put it in the keypress event
        'putting it in the textchanged event is problematic and not recommended.
        Dim OriginalText As String = ComboBox1.Text
        If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then
            If ComboBox1.SelectionLength > 0 Then
                ComboBox1.Text = ComboBox1.Text
                ComboBox1.SelectionLength = 0
                ComboBox1.SelectionStart = ComboBox1.Text.Length
            End If
        End If
        If Not IsTextKey(e.KeyCode) Then Exit Sub
        Dim Filter As String = ComboBox1.Text & "*"
        If Filter.Length = 1 Then Exit Sub
        For I = 0 To ComboBox1.Items.Count - 1
            If LCase(ComboBox1.Items(I).ToString) Like LCase(Filter) Then
                ComboBox1.SelectedItem = ComboBox1.Items(I)
                ComboBox1.Select(OriginalText.Length, (ComboBox1.Text.Length - OriginalText.Length))
                Exit Sub
            End If
        Next
    End Sub
    Function IsTextKey(ByVal Key As Integer) As Boolean
        Select Case True
            Case Key = Keys.Up : Return False
            Case Key = Keys.Down : Return False
            Case Key = Keys.Left : Return False
            Case Key = Keys.Right : Return False
            Case Key = Keys.Back : Return False
            Case Key = Keys.Delete : Return False
            Case Key = Keys.LWin : Return False
            Case Key = Keys.RWin : Return False
                'add whatever I missed
                'return false if the key either removes text from the textbox 
                'or does not produce a character
            Case Else
                'return true if the key produces a visible character(including space)
                Return True
        End Select
    End Function
End Class
```

Comment: This is BRILLIANT! Wow. It's mostly working. The only issue it has is if there is a `/` in the string - it does change the index, but the string doesn't get populated back into the `combobox`.

Comment: lol so it _does_ work...but only if i type really fast and press `enter` really quickly. It's trying to filter after every key up, which is not wanted.

Comment: So change which event you're doing your filtering in, and modify it to your needs.

Comment: you can remove the part that highlights the "guessed" piece and make it where it just selects the first match faithfully, so you won't have to press enter, but that is problematic that it will complete "test1" when you're at typing "test", even though you were going to type "test2"... I think as-is, it should solve your problem

Answer (score 7):

Disclaimer: this is written in C# - let me know if you need it translated to VB.

```
private void comboBox1_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, PreviewKeyDownEventArgs e)
{
    //It's important to also check that the Combo Box is displaying its Drop Down. If
    //you want this to execute even when it is not displayed, remove the check for
    //comboBox1.DroppedDown.
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter && comboBox1.DroppedDown &&
        !string.IsNullOrEmpty(comboBox1.Text))
    {
        int index;
        //Attempt to locate the string typed in by the user. An index of -1
        //means it was not found.
        if ((index = comboBox1.FindStringExact(comboBox1.Text)) != -1)
        {
            //Update the SelectedIndex.
            comboBox1.SelectedIndex = index;
        }
    }
}
```

Interestingly, the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.selectionchangecommitted.aspx) say that we should be using the `SelectionChangeCommitted` event instead of the `SelectedIndexChanged` event when handling selection changes made by the user. It is necessary to do so in this case as the `SelectedIndexChanged` event fires twice using my approach.

**Edit:**

To prevent the user from having to type the entire string, use the advice from Adi's answer: go to the properties of the combo box and set set `AutoCompleteMode` to `SuggestAppend` and `AutoCompleteSource` to `ListItems` - I actully used these settings when creating my answer, so it should work for you.

Comment: I appreciate this but since I don't want the user to have to type the whole string in the combo box for it to find a match (some of the strings are 20+ characters) this isn't what I need. Great snippet though. Thanks!

Comment: Gaaaah it's getting REALLLY close. Ok that does make it recognize that there is a change in index. HOWEVER, no matter what I type (whatever index I WANT it to go to), on enter it gets set to the first item in the list.

Comment: it seems like it's good on the text but when it gets to `If((index = comboBox1.FindStringExact(comboBox1.Text)) <> -1)` it's just returning `1`... it's not finding the index of the string...

Comment: @redhotspike could you update your question with the items actually contained in the combobox? Also, make sure that comboBox1 is the correct name in your code.

Comment: i've edited my question to include a sampling of combobox items.

Answer (score 4):

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_KeyUp(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.KeyUp
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then
        MessageBox.Show(ComboBox1.SelectedText)
        Call SomeMethod()
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: this would work great in conjunction with what @AdiKonstantin suggests but the text is being cleared when the user presses enter after a match is found. Do you have any suggestions for that?

Answer (score 3):

I believe that you should set `AutoCompleteMode` to **`SuggestAppend`** and `AutoCompleteSource` to **`ListItems`**. This way, if what you type in is sustainable with the items loaded in the ComboBox, by writing it down and finding that item, when pressed <kbd>Enter</kbd>, the `SelectedIndexChanged` will be fired (even if a match wouldn't be found - the first in the list will be selected)

I've prepared [something](http://www13.zippyshare.com/v/27418550/file.html) to point out this to you.

Regards,

Adi Konstantin

Comment: This is definitely closer to what I need - EXCEPT, when a match is found, and the user clicks enter, the text in the `combobox` is cleared...any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Subscribe to the KeyPressed event:

```
Private Sub yourComboBox_KeyPressed(sender As System.Object, e As System.KeyPressedEventArgs) Handles yourComboBox.KeyPressed
    If e.KeyChar.Equals((char)Keys.Enter) Then
        Call SomeMethod()
End If
```

Answer (score 2):

this will helps your problems

```
 Private Sub ComboBox1_KeyDown(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.KeyDown
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then
        MsgBox("hello")'call some functions
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: This is a little bit closer; the `KeyDown` event is being called, but it doesn't actually change the index of the `ComboBox`.

Comment: actually what you need, please tell me the details.....in the above code, if you press enter key in particular index of the combobox, you can perform functions inside the key event.

Answer (score 2):

Can you let me know if this works for you?

```
    Private Sub ComboBox1_KeyPress(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.KeyPress
      If e.KeyChar = Chr(13) Then
        ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender, e)
      End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
      MsgBox(ComboBox1.Text)
      'Your code here
    End Sub
```

Comment: thanks but it had the same result as the suggestion by @Sean Vaughn

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem when the combobox dropdownstyle was set to simple with autocomplete set to append, sourcing from my listitems.  My workaround was to have a string variable save the combobox text upon each textchanged event.  That way, when ENTER is pressed, you can retrieve the deleted text and reassign it to the combobox text.

'Global declaration

```
'Global declaraion
dim selected_text as string = ""

 Private Sub combobox_textchanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles combobox.TextChanged
        If combobox.Text IsNot Nothing And combobox.Text <> "" Then
            selected_text = combobox.Text
        End If
 End Sub

Private Sub combobox_keydown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles combobox.KeyDown
        If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then
            combobox.Text = selected_text
            'put logic here
        End If
End Sub
```

There are some great answers above, but I liked that I didn't need to sort out all the command keys and arrows etc.

Answer (score 0):

Close the list manualy on PreviewKeyDown event:

```
Private Sub cmbStatus_PreviewKeyDown(sender As ComboBox, e As PreviewKeyDownEventArgs) Handles cmbStatus.PreviewKeyDown
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then sender.DroppedDown = False
End Sub
```